# Renaming iOS App after submission to AppStore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, universal

I just developed and submitted the App. In development and testing purpose, I gave the App name as "XYZ" and while preparing for AppStore I gave a name in iTunes connect as "XYZ-abcd".

And while trying to upload binary it showed error, so I had to change it's name to "XYZ-abcd" but after running the App on my phone, the whole text doesn't shows up. I have already uploaded the binary and status shows: Upload received.

How to change it?

Answer (score 6):

There are few different places where an app's "name" is used:

1. The bundle identifier - this is the `com.yourcompany.my-cool-app` id that the system uses to identify your app on iOS and in iTunes Connect.  This is just something unique to you that doesn't change for the life of your app as long as it is live on the app store.  I have an app whose identifier is nothing like the name that's displayed on the app store
2. The bundle name - this is name that is displayed by iOS (under the icon on the springboard, in settings, etc.). You can make this short or abbreviated in order to not truncate, but it must be similar to:
3. The App Name (on iTunes Connect). This is what is actually displayed on the app store when users search for your app.  My app uses the longform app name plus a dash and a 'subtitle' if that's what you want to call it.  For example, Tweetbot (not my app): "Tweetbot — A Twitter Client with Personality for iPhone"

It sounds like the error you are encountering is related to you changing the bundle identifier in your app, but not having the bundle id match in iTC.  Change your bundle id to whatever you have on iTC and it should upload just fine.

Comment: I am facing issue you mentioned in point 3. How can I change now?

Comment: Is that your bundle id in iTC? Or your bundle id in your project? They need to match.